# PHP mail bounce emails due to anchor tag

Tags: php, email, anchor

I try to add anchor tag in email but as i try to send email after add anchor tag its bounce back email when is add http or https in href
following is the example of bounce

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">click here</a>
```

but when I remove `http://` from href email send but at client end this show as

```
"www.example.comclick here"
```

I am sending email from php using smtp method

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the [Code Sample `{}`](https://i.imgur.com/3ppJhiE.png) toolbar button—I've done it for you this time. You also have a preview pane right below the editor so you can see how changes look like before you publish them.

Comment: Please share your email code in order for us to review and trace the error.

Comment: code include smtp information so difficult to share. but as i write above the problem with anchor tag http

Comment: Your emails are most certainly being filtered as spam.

Comment: as I told its bounce when i try to add http in href in anchor tag so what is the solution. As i write code above what i try to send in email message